# Dax consecutive occurrences

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have trouble fixing the consecutive column as a calculated column, the dax code works for certain ID however it doesn't work for every single ID. I think it is because the sort order is not sorted properly but I couldn't fix it. It is supposed to reproduce similar results as ID: 1. Months column is just 1 if total usage = 0 or not.

Consecutive is supposed to count consecutive total usage = 0 and reset the count if total usage is > 0 for the next month.

ID 2 should be 1,2,3,4,5,6 and ID 3 should be 1,2

```
consecutive = 
VAR ID = 'Total Usage'[ID]
VAR CurrentDate = 'Total Usage'[Date]
VAR PrevDate =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Total Usage'[Date]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(' Total Usage'),
            ' Total Usage'[ID] = ID &&
            ' Total Usage'[Date] < CurrentDate &&
            ' Total Usage'[Total Usage] > 0
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK(PrevDate),
        IF(
            ' Total Usage'[Total Usage] = 0,
            1,
            0
        ),
        IF(
            ' Total Usage'[Total Usage] = 0,
            DATEDIFF(PrevDate, CurrentDate, MONTH),
            0
        )
    )
```

| ID | Date | Total Usage | Months | consecutive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/27/2022 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1/27/2023 | 200 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5/27/2023 | 20000 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 6/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 5/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 6/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 4/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 5/27/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |